# How to put first objects into other object in java script and to make a single object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two input objects.

**1.**

```
var inputData1 = {
    'st1': {
        'name': 'k1',
        'rollNo': 'abc'
    },
    'st2': {
        'name': 'k2',
        'rollNo': 'pqr'
    }
};
```

**2.**

```
var inputData2 = {
    'result': {
        'data': 'sdg'
    }
};
```

How to put first object into the other object. This is the expected output :

**Output Object**

```
var output = {
    'result': {
        'data': 'sdg',
        'st1': {
            'name': 'k1',
            'rollNo': 'abc'
        },
        'st2': {
            'name': 'k2',
            'rollNo': 'pqr'
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: `inputData1` cannot have multiple values with same key `st`.

Answer (score 1):

let say this is your first object.

```
var inputData1 = {
    'st1':{'name':'k1', 'rollNo':'abc'},
    'st2': {'name':'k2', 'rollNo':'pqr'}
};
```

and this is second object

```
var inputData2 = {
    'result': {
        "data": "sdg"
    }
};
```

you can use simply like this

```
Object.assign(inputData2.result, inputData1);

console.log(inputData2);
```

Comment: @raghavkumar You can then upvote the answers that helped you and choose one of them as the accepted one!

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is the following :

```
// returns a new independant copy from the inputs
function combine(inputData1, inputData2) {
    if (!inputData1 instanceof Object || !inputData2 instanceof Object) {
        return {};
    }
    let output = Object.assign({}, inputData2);
    Object.assign(output.result, inputData1);
    return output;
}

var output = combine(inputData1, inputData2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first off you can't have duplicate keys in an object.  I suggest numbering them, and then you can just assign the contents of st1, st2 to the matchibng props in the output onject:

```
var inputData1 = {
    'st1':{'name':'k1', 'rollNo':'abc'},
    'st2': {'name':'k2', 'rollNo':'pqr'}
};

var inputData2 = {
    'result': {
         "data": "sdg"
    }
}
```

So now you want to use `Object.assign(obj, obj)` to combine your objects:

```
var output = Object.assign(inputData1.result, inputData2);
```

This will combine your objects and give you what you want I hope.  This method was added in ES6.

Let me know if this works, and remember to pick a winning answer :P

Comment: You are missing your `.result` after `inputData1` no?